# Different repr for REPL?

Tags: python, debugging

I want to present an alternative `repr` for an object **iff** it's being dumped into the REPL directly, not as part of a `Collection` and not as part of a different function call; this alternate representation contains a lot of very useful debugging information, but inherently breaks its use as a *composable* “repr” result.

Is this achievable in Python?

I tried this, but it didn't work as the "alternate" representation got printed unconditionally (but the stack isn't any deeper):

```py
class Foo:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        # Return a string which can be passed to __new__ to reconstruct this object
        ...
    def __repr__(self):
        if inspect.stack()[1].filename != '<stdin>':
            # Use a "proper" representation which is composeable
            return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({str(self)!r})'
        # Object is being dumped as a singleton into the REPL, break out the fireworks
        return f'{self.__pretty_print_extra_debug_repr()}\n{self.__class__.__name__}({str(self)!r})'
```

Comment: Your use case sounds more like you'd want to mess with [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook), which can special-case for your object's type and defer to the previous-set implementation for everything else.

Comment: @user2722968 I didn't see any API in there that would accomplish what I'm hoping. Are you suggesting to monkey-patch `sys` itself?

Comment: It's not monkey-patching, this is an explicit hook that allows you to customize how values are displayed in the REPL. But it only gets the top-level value, not nested values.

Comment: Did you try to debug the `if inspect.stack()[1].filename != '<stdin>':` logic, for example by testing the value of `inspect.stack()[1].filename`?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude, the API *is* to set `sys.displayhook` to your own value. It's obviously a global configuration, and if you run into problems, you'd need to take care to defer to whatever was the previous hook-function (effectively stacking them). I've outlined an example as an answer.

Comment: Stupid workaround I ultimately used, for reference: I prepended each line of the "extra" information blob with `'\n# '`, and I appended `'\n'` to the entire "extra" information blob. Now the objects do "survive" an `eval(repr(...))` round-trip, even when contained in lists or tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) for this purpose

Something to the tune of:

```py
import sys

class MyType:
    def __init__(self, foobar):
        self.foobar = foobar


def my_displayhook(value):
    if isinstance(value, MyType):
        # Just for `MyType`, everything else we just use `repr()`
        reprstr = f'Please now hear this: {value.foobar}'
    else:
        reprstr = repr(value)
    sys.stdout.write(reprstr + '\n')


old_displayhook = sys.displayhook  # save for later, maybe we want to un-hook
sys.displayhook = my_displayhook

foo = MyType('foo')

# This will print the normal `repr` of a `MyType`-instance
print(repr(foo))

# but evaluating `foo` as an expression in a REPL will print "Please now hear..."
```